Checking if the relationship between a composite score and its components across variates covariates
I have created a continuous composite score, C, which consists of scores A + B. I have a predictor variable, D. This would produce 3 different regression formulas, where predictor D has a coefficient for each dependent variable: A, B, and C.
I aim to compare the coefficient for the predictor across A, B, and C to see if they are statistically different.
What would be the appropriate statistical test in this situation?
